# Understanding the Plotly camera controls in Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I have looked at the Plotly docs and other resources, but they just give example views - not what each individual vector coordinate *actually* corresponds to. I want to rotate the default vertical view slightly by a few degrees, and rotate a few degrees so the x-axis has most of the view (BUT still see some of the y-axis). How much of a change in the x,y,z coordinates affect the view. E.g. changing x=1.25 to 1.5 rotates clockwise horizontally by 20 degrees.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import numpy as np
pio.renderers.default='browser'

X,Y = np.random.randn(100),np.random.randn(100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

z = lambda x,y : x*y

Z = z(X,Y)

fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(z=Z,x=X,y=Y))

# Default
camera = dict(eye=dict(x=1.25, y=1.25, z=1.25))
fig.update_scenes(camera=camera)

fig.show()
```

Comment: I'm not expert here, and stumbled across this trying to figure out what coordinate frame the camera controls are using.  But I think you probably understand the camera based on what you wrote.  I can definitely make the camera do what you're suggesting, but by using:  `fig.update_layout(dict(scene_camera=dict(x=1.25, y=1.25, z=1.25)))` instead of `fig.update_scenes`, which I see in the documentation, but isn't what they use in the camera controls demo page.